# WSO2 Api manager 4.1.0 - Control plane -s eparate devportal and publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

It is possible install wso2 api manager 4.1.0 like this:

- 2 GW instances
- 1 Control plane (only publisher)
- 1 Control plane ( only devportal)

It is possible separate control plane on one devportal and one publisher? i cannot find manual on this. I found only this profiles https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since APIM 4.0.0, Publisher, Devportal, and Key manager profiles have been deprecated.The Control Plane profile was introduced as a combination of those 3 and traffic manager.

In order to achieve your requirement, you might have to setup 2 control plane servers with different hostnames[1] and route the requests through a loadbalancer or an ingress controller accordingly.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/#changing-the-api-m-hostname